# Postman RSA Encryption

Tags: rsa, postman

I would like to utilize postman to test a REST API that requires one of the input fields to be encrypted with RSA encryption.

I see that postman provides the functionality through `require('crypto-js')` to encrypt using AES encryption, but I that library does not provide RSA encryption. How can I use post man to automate RSA encryption?

The flow would work like this:

1. Call a REST API that returns an RSA public key
2. Store the RSA public key in a variable
3. Utilize that public key to encrypt an value in the following request
   before sending

Answer (score 4):

I have created a little ¨library¨ to use cryptographic methods in Postman Pre-request and Tests script, RSA is totally supported, have a look to the tutorial here, is very easy to use.

https://joolfe.github.io/postman-util-lib/

Best Regards.

Here is an example of how to RSA encrypt using the 'RSAOAEP' alg:

```
// RSAOAEP signature example
const pubkey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n' +
'MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAstXEkU/agbNkQgh6a9DV\n' +
'C/WXGmNy8g+hdTOBhYUk5PfZCwTNt5SCYBLjIPhs2ZRrNuCN3PhwHRQPQOTsS6Nl\n' +
'Bzw+SjPVFBhPcbMHbJWnC87Q5ID/uAuwJjcUQXUTVspwIgfRmHvuuT7w7AYnCNvz\n' +
'B5TuPj2vVH8rij9BXkAHambaeGG7L10MPeUiVU6M0F/QKCJhEWAYGEt4NffSXETx\n' +
'zHSl8nyXxVJfnjxVhnZyZVXTIpLwvRy04hnkAoFexh7npRtnQdsLuIHtaJsm7gFY\n' +
'mxhr3Nxbh9p1pC7fHpJ+jMcxAAhA07WqYf6lOsxXHfPav1FEMX214YTsKTw68xqo\n' +
'DwIDAQAB\n' +
'-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n'

const fileContent = 'My file content comes here...'
const keyObj = pmlib.rs.KEYUTIL.getKey(pubkey)
const encHex = pmlib.rs.KJUR.crypto.Cipher.encrypt(fileContent, keyObj, 'RSAOAEP')

console.log(encHex)
// will return the hexadecimal encoded, can be converted to many format ussing the library too
```

Comment: I have add this exmaple to the postman collection in the library here https://github.com/joolfe/postman-util-lib/tree/master/postman

Comment: How do I make use of this JSON you have shared on github in the previous comment?

Comment: Hi Steve, the JSON are postman collections so you just need to import in your POSTMAN app, as described here https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection-runs/working-with-data-files/

Comment: What is the fileContent? Is it the .pem file?

Comment: My key format has: "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", so the pmlib.rs.KEYUTIL.getKey(pubkey) throws me an error, is there a way to make it work? thanks in advance 
cc: @joliva

Answer (score 0):

I dit it.

you need https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge
and compile it, not from cdn, can not work

load from your script

```js
1.load script
var server = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("server");

if (!postman.getEnvironmentVariable("forgeJS")) {
    pm.sendRequest("http://" + server + "/res/forge.js", function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            postman.setEnvironmentVariable("forgeJS", res.text());
        }
    })
}

2.eval script and encrypt

var password = '123456';

var public_key = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n' +
    pm.environment.get("rsaKey") + '\n' +
    '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

var jsscript = pm.environment.get("forgeJS");
eval(jsscript);

console.info(public_key)
var publicKey = forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem(public_key);
var encryptedText = forge.util.encode64(publicKey.encrypt("123456", 'RSA-OAEP', { // server Java private decrypt
    md: forge.md.sha256.create(),
    mgf1: {
        md: forge.md.sha1.create()
    }
}));

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("password", encryptedText);
```

Comment: Does this still work for you? Even after `eval`-ing the forge.js, I get `ReferenceError: forge is not defined`.

Comment: it is because postman.setEnvironmentVariable("forgeJS", res.text()); executed in async callback.If ok for you - execute first part in pre-request script. Or use trick from here https://community.postman.com/t/executing-sync-requests-programmatically-from-a-pre-request-or-test-scripts/14678/2